# multi-row sqlite db update in iOS CoreData

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController with a UITableView to present data in an iOS app from an underlying sqlite database.  At a certain points in the flow of the app, I need to update flags in multiple rows of the database from a separate controller.

I don't think iterating thru all the objects, changing the flag, then resaving is ideal.

Is there a best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

1. Resign the fetched controller as delegate (very important)
2. Perform change to CoreData and save context
3. Assign again fetched controller delegate and execute fetch again
4. Call reload table, only visible row will be updated

you can deal with this with the usual CoreData notification about save and change of context.
You can perform any operations you want, they will be notified only when the context is saved.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  The change I want to make in step 2 is something to the affect of `update mytable set myflag=2 where myflag==1` for roughly a thousand rows in the table.  Would you do that by iterating thru the NSManagedObjects one at a time, by accessing the db file directly and peforming sql updates, or thru another mechanism?